# Error MT0026 on Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to run an iOS simulator from my Xamarin Forms project. I had it working a month ago, and when I returned to it, I get the following error:

```
error MT0026: Could not parse the command line argument '-sdk': Version string portion was too short or too long.
```

I updated all the NuGet packages and updated Xamarin itself.

The only thing I can find on the issue is here: [Xamarin.iOS Errors](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT0026_Could_not_parse_the_command_line_argument_)

Also, my mac is up-to-date and I made sure xcode was up-to-date as well.

Comment: Check last comment from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15171/error-loading-project-version-string-portion-was-too-short-or-too-long

Comment: FYI: the MT0026 error also showed up in a Xamarin project when the MinimumOS version in the Info.plist was "10" instead of "10.0" with command line argument -targetver

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had exactly the same error when I first started Visual Studio on MacOS. For me the list of device emulators was empty. The only available device listed was "Generic Device". After I restarted Visual Studio all available simulation devices turned up:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, i don't have any simulators available here. Only generic sim

EDIT: I believe it's because I'm not on the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this appears whenever you make an important OS update. Why?
Because usually something gets changed into Xcode and one needs to open the app to agree whatever they want you to agree.

After that, restart Visual Studio and everything is back to normal.